# Create a Timer using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java2, countdowntimer

Currently I'm using a `CountDownTimer` that **count down** from a number and `onFinish` **run an action** and reset the timer, starting the count down from another number.

For example inputs like this:

```
Remaining time = 13 | Interval = 30
```

Result in a output like this:

```
13 12 .. 3 2 1 0 30 29 .. 3 2 1 0 30 29 ...
```

I've tried to create a chain that generate the desired output using `interval`, `delay` and other `operators` but I'm yet to find a solution.

Comment: Use interval and map it to the desired output value while tracking the current value in some field and resetting it upon zero.

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions

```
fun countDown(startCounter: Long, nextCounter: Long): Observable<Long> {
    return Observable.intervalRange(startCounter, startCounter+2, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map { 2*startCounter - it }
            .flatMap { if(it >= 0) Observable.just(it) else countDown( nextCounter, nextCounter) }

}
```

And then use it like

```
countDown(13, 30)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe({
                System.out.println(it.toString())
            }, {
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
```

The result should be as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a range, repeat it indefinitely and drop first couple of items, then delay every emission:

```
fun countdownTimer(remainingTime: Long, interval: Int): Flowable<Int> {
    return Flowable.range(0, interval + 1)
        .map { interval - it }
        .repeat()
        .skip(interval - remainingTime)
        .concatMap { Flowable.just(it).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
}
```